# Getting a function name as a string

Tags: r, function

Say I have a bunch of functions, each with something like`MyFunction.1`, etc.  I want to pass these functions into another function, which prints out a small report.  Ideally I'd like to be able to label sections of a report by which function is being used to generate the results.

So are there any nice ways of getting the name of a predefined function as a string?

Answer (score 71):

I was wanting the same thing, and remembered `library(foo)` didn't need quotes, this is what it does:

```
package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

Comment: good observation! objectName = as.character(quote(object)) works as well

Comment: What is the answer? I do not see what this has to do with the question.

Answer (score 27):

Another approach would be to pass the names of the functions into your report function, and then get the functions themselves with the `get()` command.  For instance:

```
function.names <- c("which","all")
fun1 <- get(function.names[1])
fun2 <- get(function.names[2])
```

Then you have the names in your original character vector, and the functions have new names as you defined them.  In this case, the `all` function is now being called as `fun2`:

```
> fun2(c(TRUE, FALSE))
[1] FALSE
```

Or, if you really want to keep the original function names, just assign them locally with the assign function:

```
assign(function.names[2], get(function.names[2]))
```

If you run this command right now, you will end up with the `all` function in your `".GlobalEnv"`.  You can see this with `ls()`.

Comment: Was not really the authors question and is a not so nice workaround. See match.call(fun)[2] below.

Answer (score 9):

That may lead to `parse(eval(...))` at which point you are open for this critique:

```
R> library(fortunes)
R> fortune("parse")

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)

R>
```

So do your functions have to be called `MyFunction.1` etc pp?

Comment: Hah - I was afraid I'd get that fortune.  I just wanted to be able to have a function I can call like compare.distribution.methods(c(two.choice, go.left, simple.random.sample), and get a table of results for each method in the vector.  The nice-to-have would be not having to pass in a labels vector with the names I want, but that's certainly another option.  I was just hoping for something that'd do it for me.  If this is not part of the R flow, then all the better that this question is answered thus.

Comment: The S3 method dispatch does that for you!  Don't fear the "OO", this would be a nice simple example to start using it.  If only I had some kind and gentle docs to point you to ...  Maybe Chambers "Software for Data Analysis" book from last year?

Comment: I am pretty certain the MAIN CORE of the `R hyperdrive` runs on `eval` and `parse` and `substitute` and `deparse` ... I guess those tools are only for the grownups.  I don't have the VISOR like La Forge on Star Trek, so I guess I am not allowed to operate the hyperdrive.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the unevaluated arguments of a function via `match.call`.  For example:

```
> x <- function(y) print(match.call()[2])
> x(lm)
lm()
```

Comment: True, not but helpful here. If you say "z <- lm" and then x(z) you get "z", not "lm".

Comment: True, although it's unclear what the right behavior is then.  Which function is "canonical" and should be printed?

Comment: In a functional language, the name of the function is not really important. You can easily rename functions, or have functions without names. The match.call function just gives you the name of the variable that held the function when it was being called, so in that sense, it's doing the only thing it can do. I don't know that "canonical" really comes into it...

Comment: This is all true, but then what is the right answer in the context of the original question.  I imagine Hamilton wants a function `foo` that generates reports of the form

    > foo(MyFunction.1, MyFunction.2)
    MyFunction.1 867
    MyFunction.2 5309

The question is if Hamilton sets `MyFunction.1 <- MyFunction.3`, should the report print out `MyFunction.1` or `MyFunction.3`?

Comment: I should also mention that many functions, such as `lm`, use `match.call` to label its summary reports.

Comment: MyFunction.1. Anything else requires telepathy on the part of the interpreter! The original name of the function is lost, per the S language definition, when you assign it to another variable. If you want the *original* name of the function, you have to store it in one of the several ways described above.

Comment: So in light of this, what was your objection with my solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just want to provide an example to show the advantage and limitation in this issue:

I want to "save" a function with its name, as an option that would be used in another function:

```
R> foreach(..., .combine=test_fun) {...}
```

The `test_fun` is the name of the function, and of course

```
R> mode(test_fun)  
[1] "function"
```

When I use it in foreach, I just need the function name, while `test_fun` can be an existing function (e.g. `cbind`). So, `test_fun` is assigned by

```
R> test_fun <- get('cbind')
```

or

```
R> test_fun <- assign('cbind', get('cbind'))
```

So, you got the function here

```
R> test_fun  
function (..., deparse.level = 1)   
.Internal(cbind(deparse.level, ...))
```

actually, the original name can't be maintained, so you have no way to convert `test_fun` back to string `"cbind"`.

```
R> deparse(substitute(test_fun))  
[1] "test_fun"
```

I unfortunately need to deparse the foreach code so want the original name shown in the string. This means that the only way is to save `'cbind'` as a string and creating such a function object brings no benefit in this case.

Answer (score 3):

When a function is passed around as an object, it loses its name. See, for example, the results of the following lines:

```
str(lm)
lm
```

You can get the arguments and the body of the function, but not the name.

My suggestion would be to construct a named list of functions, where the name could be printed:

```
> somefns <- list(lm=lm, aggregate=aggregate)
> str(somefns)
List of 2
 $ lm       :function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)  
 $ aggregate:function (x, ...) 

> somefns[[1]](dist ~ speed, data=cars)

Call:
somefns[[1]](formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed  
     -17.58         3.93  

> names(somefns)[[1]]
[1] "lm"
```

Comment: Two nice alternatives [have just been posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621108/keeping-function-names-when-stored-in-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

what about this:

```
deparse(quote(foo.bar))
```

Comment: That just returns `foo.bar`

Comment: not exactly: it returns `"foo.bar"`, that is, the requested string.  (but I'm not any more using R, since 2012...)

Answer (score 3):

Nice observation by @nfultz, so the answer to this thread's question would be :-

```
workingFunction <- Function(f)
{ functionName <- as.character(substitute(f)) }
```

Or

```
workingFunction <- Function(f)
{ functionName <- deparse(substitute(f)) }
```

All the other answers would simply return the parameter name itself ('f' in the example above) - I tried them all since I've been working on a function and experienced this issue of not being able to retrieve a function's name inside another function wherein the first is passed as parameter to the second function while calling it. Hope my answer helps to all those who might be stuck for the same!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked wonderfully for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled a lot with this issue and unfortunately the given solutions were not working out for me, but I came up with a way to get the name with R6 classes.

Here a minimal example:

```
NameProvider <-
  R6::R6Class(
    "NameProvider",
    base::list(
      get_fun_name = function(fun_name) { return(fun_name)})
    )

NameUser <-
  R6::R6Class(
    "NameUser",
    base::list(
      do_something = function(fun)
        {
          np <- NameProvider$new()
          fname <- np$get_fun_name(fun_name = base::as.character(base::substitute(fun)))
          do_the_thing <- paste0("THIS IS ", base::toupper(fname), "!!!")
          return(do_the_thing)
        }
        )
      )

nu <- NameUser$new()
nu$do_something(fun = mean)
```

The class `NameProvider` just returns the name as a string and in the class `NameUser` the call for `base::as.character(base::substitute(...))` is made.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience rlang::ensyms function leads a concise solution and works best.

```
library(rlang)
get_func_name <- function(  ...  ){

     name <- map(rlang::ensyms(  ... ) , as.character) 
                
     unlist(name)
}
    
    
    get_func_name(str)
    #"str"
    
    #even itself :)
    get_func_name(str , formatC , get_func_name)
    # "str"       "formatC" "get_func_name" 
    #
```