# Get the name of a function contained in variable

Tags: r, functional-programming

Certainly a very basic question but I do not have the answer:

I have a vector of function:

```
func1 <- function(u) u
func2 <- function(u) NA
func3 <- function(u) 1

funcs = c(func1, func2, func3)
```

I loop over every function using `sapply`, and I want to find a function `command` that retrieves the name of the function:

```
res=sapply(funcs, function(f){
    command(f)
})
```

So that `res` is then:

```
c("func1","func2","func3")
```

Comment: @Paul John, I do not pass the function directly but a variable containing the function. However, I am terribly afraid that my problem has no solution.

Comment: Gah, I keep confusing myself. @JohnPaul That solution won't work. As I originally attempted to say (and I think I was right) I don't think there is way to do this. The solution is to create a named vector in the first place.

Comment: @joran You are right. It seems that the `funcs` vector does not automatically store the function names in any way.

Comment: As the other comments suggest,  only the function itself is stored, not the named object, when you do `c(func1,...)` .

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621108/keeping-function-names-when-stored-in-an-object/25621265#25621265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no way to get the names if funcs is created with c, here is a convenience function for creating **funcs** that preserves the names:

```
cn <- function(...)
{
      # call c() on parameters supplied, adding names
      cnames <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L],as.character)
      out <- c(...)
      names(out) <- cnames
      return(out)
}
funcs = cn(func1, func2, func3)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
 flist<-ls(patt='func*')
 flist[1]
[1] "func1"

 do.call(flist[1],list(5))
# 5
```