# R How to check if input is a specific function

Tags: r

I have a function that takes an input of a function.

```
 myfunc <- function(FUN){}
```

There, I want to check if FUN is a `mean`, and perform some more task

```
 myfunc <- function(FUN){
      ``some tasks here``
      if(FUN==mean){``some more task here``} # this FUN==mean is not valid
 }
```

However, it seems FUN can't be compared with this way. Is there a way to check if a specific function is inputed?

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638372/how-to-compare-functions

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks. identical() works in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses [`checkmate::assert_function()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/checkmate/versions/1.8.3/topics/checkFunction) for a little extra security.

```
myfunc <- function(FUN){
  checkmate::assert_function(mean)

  if( identical(FUN, base::mean) ){
    return( TRUE )
  } else {
    return( FALSE )
  }
}

myfunc(mean)    # TRUE
myfunc(meanie)  # FALSE
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567718/getting-a-function-name-as-a-string) prompts the `substitute()` and alternative solutions in a slightly more complicated scenario.

*edit*: followed @spacedman's advice and replaced `substitute(FUN) == "mean"` inside the 'if' condition to make it more robust (particularly against sociopaths who name their function to [mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137110/what-does-the-following-object-is-masked-from-packagexxx-mean) `base::mean()`).

Comment: This works if any function *named* `mean` is passed. This might not be the base R function `mean`. To compare with the base R function `mean()` use `identical(FUN, base::mean)`

Comment: @Spacedman, I didn't consider that.  It's updated to reflect your improvement.